# Почему порядок файлов в консоли отличается от порядка в проводнике

Tags: windows, cmd

Обнаружил интересную закономерность. Представим, что есть папка: `C:\test`. В этой папке 4 изображения:

[image: скрин проводника]

По заголовку столбца на скриншоте видно, что установлен порядок сортировки по имени. Далее, лезем в консоль:

```
C:\Users\host> cd C:\test

C:\test>dir /O:N
 Том в устройстве C не имеет метки.
 Серийный номер тома: 080B-01C6

 Содержимое папки C:\test

30.05.2019  22:44    <DIR>          .
30.05.2019  22:44    <DIR>          ..
09.05.2019  19:23           297 624 2016-07-18-17-19-47-393.jpg
09.05.2019  19:23            52 996 59Xt_3MUvkk.jpg
25.07.2015  04:51         6 008 045 DSC_2786.JPG
10.07.2017  12:56         5 589 186 DSC_2786+.JPG
               4 файлов     11 947 851 байт
               2 папок  40 999 325 696 байт свободно
```

Что мы здесь видим? Отличие порядка файлов налицо. Если приглядеться, можно заметить еще отличия по дате, но с датой там понятно (свои тонкости по дате создания, изменения и пр).

А вот с порядком сортировки по имени вопрос остался открытым... Есть идеи, почему так?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/319827/the-sort-order-for-files-and-folders-whose-names-contain-numerals-is-d

Answer (score 1):

Windows сортирует странным образом. Там где есть цифры в имени файла в начале она считает целое натуральное число до ближайшей не цифры и сортирует по ним. Так например 2016-07-18-17-19-47-393.jpg это 2016, а 59Xt_3MUvkk.jpg это 59. И получаем что сортировка по имени даст вначале 59 а потом 2016.

Comment: Это не странный способ, это называется естественная сортировка. При естественной сортировке вы получите Photo2.jpg, потом Photo19.jpg (2<19), а при алфавитной сортировке - Photo19.jpg, потом Photo2.jpg (т.к. 1<2)

Comment: @insolor это странный способ для таких совершенно разных имён.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, для совершенно разных имен - человеку вообще все равно в каком порядке они будут. А для имен файлов с номером - удобнее.

Answer (score 1):

Window Explorer показывает файлы отсортированными, в вашем случае по имени. Как уже отметили, используется естественная сортировка, где 2016 больше 59.

Консоль не сортирует никак, а показывает файлы в том порядке, в котором они записаны в каталоге. Каталог NTFS хранит записи о файлах в виде дерева; при обходе дерева они выводятся в лексикографическом порядке, и в этом случае файл 2016... идет первым, потому что 2 < 5.

Comment: В вопросе команда `dir /O:N`, так что нельзя сказать что тут "файлы в том порядке, в котором они записаны в каталоге".

Comment: @insolor, верно, просмотрел ключ. Но по сути это ничего не меняет - без ключа выдало бы точно такой же результат, то есть простой лексикографический порядок.